# App Crashes on iOS 8.0.2 and iOS 8.1

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, xcode6.1, ios8.1

- I am developing an iPhone application. The app was running smoothly on my as well as on my clients device.
- But now client has udated his iOS version from 7.1 to iOS 8.1. Now when client goes for installing app on his device the splash screen occurs and app gets automatically minimize and he is not able to open the app again. every time when client taps on my app icon the splash screen appears and app gets minimizes automatically.
- But app is running smoothly on my device.
- I have updated my iPad to iOS version 8.1 to check whether this is version problem, but app runs successfully on it.
- I was also downloaded the new xcode 6.1 and run my project on device. It runs successfully.
- I was also deleted and recreated my certificates and provisioning profiles 3-4 times.
- But unable to get the exact problem that client is facing.

  I am unable to get any solution now. Please suggest some cases to debug this problem. I gets stuck with this problem from nearly to a week. please help me. It's urgent.As client is demanding for the build.

Comment: Debuge your code with developer Profile.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. 

But this case is not happening on my device.Code runs perfectly on my device. This is the case causes on client's device. And i am not able to get their phone.

Comment: Did you Test your app on all device like iPad Air,iPad mini and iPad2? for both iOS 7 and iOS 8 ?

Comment: Get the crash log from the client's device.

Comment: No. Let me check it on all device on simulators.And after that i will reply you what the result of it... Thanks for your positive response..

Comment: Yes app is running on every device of simulator. Only it shows linker error on iPad 2 , that was just because of the framework i have added. When i remove that framework the app runs successfully. But that is not an issue. Do you have any other suggestion ?